# How to model an if statement as a linear transformation

Tags: machine-learning, decision-theory

While working with the rectified linear activation function or ReLU, which can be mathematically expressed as ReLU(X) = max(0,X) where X

$$
X = \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ \vdots \\ x_n \end{pmatrix}, \qquad x_i \in \mathbb{R}
$$

I started thinking about the idea of a decision and how it is modeled in standard mathematics. Although I am familiar with the a notation such as:

\begin{cases}
\frac{n}{2},  & \text{if $n$ is even} \\[2ex]
3n+1, & \text{if $n$ is odd}
\end{cases}

I saw that in certain particular cases such a condition can be written as a single equation. For example, in the case of Support Vector Machines the conditions:

$$
f(\mathbf{x}_i) = \begin{cases}
w^T\mathbf{x}_i + b \geq 1, & \text{if } y_i = +1 \\
w^T\mathbf{x}_i + b \leq -1, & \text{if } y_i = -1
\end{cases}
$$

can be written as a single condition in the following way:

$$y_i(w^T\mathbf{x}_i + b) \geq 0$$

I was wondering if the ReLU function can be modeled using the same logic. For example I would want to find a matrix A, such that

$$
AX = \begin{pmatrix} x_1' \\ x_2' \\ \vdots \\ x_n' \end{pmatrix}, \qquad x_i' \in \mathbb{R}
$$
where:

$$
f(\mathbf{x}_i) = \begin{cases}
0, & \text{if } x_i \leq 0 \\
x_i & \text{if } x_i > 0
\end{cases}
$$

Does such a matrix exist or is this the whole idea of "non-linearities" in the context of activation functions and such a condition can be implemented only programmatically?

Comment: What is going on in your first definition of f? You seem to be defining a function f but have only equalities and inequalities on the right.

Comment: @DanPiponi indeed my definition of f is quite faulty. I wanted to illustrate the idea of having two different conditions (in the context of SVMs) for a vector X given a vector Y that can be combined into a single condition. I would like to achieve a similar behaviour on the ReLU function without explicitly using an "if statement". To further illustrate, take for example the function sign(x) , where x is a real number, which can be written more compactly as sign(x) = x / | x | for any non zero x. I was wondering is such a thing could be achieved with the ReLU function using matrix operations.

Comment: ReLU is, by design, nonlinear. Any composition of linear functions is linear. So even if you go via some higher dimensional space you won't be able to express ReLU as just using linear functions.

In the SVM example the goal is to express constraints in a standard form, so you can use standard linear programming. If your goal is similar, then similar tricks will be usable with ReLU. Eg. If you want to optimise subject to a constraint including the constraint $y = ReLU(x)$ you can write $y\ge 0$ and $(2y-x)^2=x^2$ and now it's in a form suitable for quadratic programming (maybe).

Comment: @DanPiponi I think I am getting the grasp of the idea. When learning about linear functions or linear mapping in Linear Algebra, I think of it in terms of additivity and homogeneity, but I now realize that we may call a nonlinear function any function whose value depends on a given condition, in this case, the ReLU function. Is that the correct way to look at it? Which specific area should I look into? A piecewise real function with many branches it's the closest to an "if statement" I can think of. Thanks!